# Проблемы с Компилятором

Tags: c++, clion

Начал изучение С++ в вузе, 1 курс, скачал CLion, написал код, но нету кнопки запуска кода, он просто серый, и выдает ошибку

CMake Error at F:/CLION/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
The C compiler

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Users/Р—Р°СЂРёРЅР°/Desktop/untitled/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):nmake /nologo cmTC_d0b44\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir\build
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d0b44.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428~1.293\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe @C:\Users\D3C3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nm2E0.tmp
testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_d0b44.exe
    F:\CLION\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428~1.293\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\D3C3~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nm35E.tmp
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~4\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1428~1.293\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir\objects1.rsp /out:cmTC_d0b44.exe /implib:cmTC_d0b44.lib /pdb:C:\Users\??????\Desktop\untitled\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_d0b44.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_d0b44.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1201) with the following output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1201: РћС€РёР±РєР° РїСЂРё Р·Р°РїРёСЃРё РІ Р±Р°Р·Сѓ РґР°РЅРЅС‹С… "C:\Users\??????\Desktop\untitled\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_d0b44.pdb" РїСЂРѕРіСЂР°РјРјС‹; РІРѕР·РјРѕР¶РЅРѕ, РЅРµ С…РІР°С‚Р°РµС‚ РјРµСЃС‚Р° РЅР° РґРёСЃРєРµ, РЅРµРґРѕРїСѓСЃС‚РёРјС‹Р№ РїСѓС‚СЊ РёР»Рё РЅРµРґРѕСЃС‚Р°С‚РѕС‡РЅРѕ РїСЂР°РІ
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: F:\CLION\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe : С‚СЋС‡С‚РЃСЂв€™С…СЌСЌв€љС‰ СЉСЋС„ "0xffffffff"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : С‚СЋС‡С‚РЃСЂв€™С…СЌСЌв€љС‰ СЉСЋС„ "0x2"
Stop.
```

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.

Comment: Уже же есть Visual Studio установленная, используйте ее и не мучайтесь. Clion еще сырой и заставляет возится с cmake.

Comment: Clion крайне для такого неудобный ,скачивайте Visual Studio Code, а если уже Clion пользуетесь,то добавьте С++ в path

Comment: Крякозябры расшифровываются в *"Ошибка при записи в базу данных ... программы; возможно, не хватает места на диске, недопустимый путь или недостаточно прав"*, а вопросики в пути не внушают доверия. Попробуйте путь без русских букв.

Comment: Присоединяюсь: CLion+компилятор от VS выглядят странно. Уж или брать VS, или CLion + MinGW.

Comment: Переходите в Linux